# How do I get my VBA button to only run on one tab?

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a button to copy inputs from a range and paste in a table elsewhere, line by line (i.e. in a table which has lines above a cell named 'end'). However when it runs, it's pasting the inputs in the same cells on different tabs as well! Any idea what I'm doing wrong please?

```
    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim Sheet As Worksheet
        For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If Sheet.Name <> "Definitions" And Sheet.Name <> "fx" And Sheet.Name <> "Needs" Then
                Sheets("sheet1").Range("A9:G9 ").Copy
                Sheet.Cells(Range("end").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            End If
        Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: What sheet do you want it to run on? Right now your `If` condition is probably not is probably not exclusive enough, as you're looping over *all* sheets in the workbook, and only excluding 3 specific sheet names from your iteration.

Comment: I want it to run on sheet1. How can I correct it to not loop over all sheets? I'm quite new to this, so thank you for your help!

Comment: Several recommendations - first, it looks like you have some obvious typos (`Range("A9:G9 ")` has an extra space in it), second, you should really avoid using a word like `Sheet` as a variable - it too closely resembles reserved words, and hurts your readability - use something like `sht` or `mysheet` instead, IMO.

Comment: On first glance it will paste into any sheet that isn't called `Definitions`, `fx` or `Needs` - so will paste into `sheet 1` and all other sheets not named in your `IF` statement.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! The space keeps automatically appearing on my code...not sure why. And I just called it 'sheet' in order to make my code more generic for this question, but I appreciate the comment about it anyway!

Comment: Thanks Darren, I see what you mean! I have included something to get the button to ignore the other sheets (which works!), but is there a simpler and more generic way to get it to ignore all other sheets other than just listing them all out?

Comment: Well for starters, if you don't want to loop over ALL worksheets, then get rid of the loop `For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` and simply operate against the desired worksheet, `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to copy from sheet1 to another place on sheet1 this will work more simply:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Worksheets("sheet1")

        'this will be even faster than the copy method below
        .Cells(.Range("end").End(xlUp).Row + 1,1).Resize(1,7).Value = _
            .Range("A9:G9").Value

        'this is the copy method that is slower
        '.Range("A9:G9").Copy
        '.Cells(.Range("end").End(xlUp).Row + 1,1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    End With


End Sub
```